# Binding flags for switching languages

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I am trying to set a multi language website on Typo3.

So far my scripts look like this:

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
    #// der Paramter L soll durchgereicht werden
    linkVars := addToList(L)
    #// der Paramter soll eindeutig sein (kein doppeltes Auftreten in einer URL)
    uniqueLinkVars = 1 
    #// content fallback
    #sys_language_fallBackOrder = 1,0
    #sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 1,0
    #sys_language_overlay = 1
    #sys_language_content = 1   
}
// Language English
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config.linkVars = 1
    config.sys_language_uid = 1
        config.language = en
        config.locale_all = en_UK
        config.htmlTag_langKey = en_UK
[global]
```

And this is under home -> Register "Resources"

```
mod.SHARED {
    defaultLanguageFlag = de.gif
    defaultLanguageLabel = Deutsch
}
```

When I call an url like www.example.com/index.php?id=17&L=1 I see the translated version and that means that it works. Now I would like to bind two flags on the frontend to select a language. Since this is the first time I am working with Typo3, I really don't know what to do. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 there's several approaches, i.e. dedicated extensions anyway most common is using `HMENU` with `special = language`

You will find samples in many places, especially in official docs, so there's no reason to paste it here:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/BasicSetupOfALocalizedWebsite/LanguageSelectorMenu/Index.html

Most probably TMENU example will be better for you just instead...

```
NO.stdWrap.setCurrent = ENGLISH || ...
```

use something like

```
NO.stdWrap.setCurrent = <img src="/fileadmin/en.png" /> || ...
```

or style it with CSS if you prefer

```
NO.stdWrap.setCurrent = <div class="flags en-flag" >English</div> || ...
```

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_language_menu and here's the ready extenion if you prefer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, biesior. I have installed the plugin that you have mentioned but it completely destroyed my website. I had to call the host to use a backup (maybe because I am not using the newest version of Typo3). Now everything is fixed. Anyway, could you please tell me where I have to put all this code into? I pasted the code from the link that you have sent to Template -> Home -> Setup but nothing happens.